# Populating Custom TableViewCell from Twitter using JSON Serialization

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, tableview, nsjsonserialization

I am new to Objective-C. I spent countless hours being stuck on getting a blank tableview, I am desperate at this point.
I am loading twitter data through a JSON call, using their API. I store everything in a NSDictionary, run a for loop to select only "text" values. I store the filtered dictionary in an object which I later use in the TableView initialization. 
I created a subclass of UItableViewCell for my custom cell.
My dataSources and delegates seem to be well connected as well (that is what I think at least)
I am having a hard time finding my problem. If someone could help me out please.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "myCell.h"
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTableView;

NSMutableArray *tweetObject;
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSString *name;
NSString *text;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    tweetObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    text = @"text";
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInGuestWithCompletion:^(TWTRGuestSession *guestSession, NSError *error) {
        if (guestSession) {
            // make API calls that do not require user auth
            NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=goofernator";
            NSError *clientError;
            NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                                     URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                     URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                                     parameters:0
                                     error:&clientError];

            if (request) {
                [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                 sendTwitterRequest:request
                 completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSData *data,
                              NSError *connectionError) {
                     if (data) {
                         // handle the response data e.g.
                         NSError *jsonError;
                         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                               JSONObjectWithData:data
                                               options:0
                                               error:&jsonError];

                         for (NSDictionary *dataDict in json) {
                             NSString *text = [dataDict valueForKeyPath: @"text"];
                             dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"bodytext",nil];
                             [tweetObject addObject:dictionary];
                            }

                     }
                     else {
                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
                     }
                 }];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return tweetObject.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    myCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[myCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [self.tweetObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtLblOutput.text = [tmpDict objectForKey:text];
    [tableView reloadData];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Here you can see the way my storyboard is put together and the references  I am using

http://postimg.org/image/79w7pqmu3/

http://postimg.org/image/ixq9kabyz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `[tableView reloadData];` in your request completion handler, after you've filled your array. Check if you receive any data. Does the array get filled with dictionary objects?

But mate, seriously, you need to read some good books about coding, your code really lacks understanding of what you're doing. Please, remove `[tableView reloadData];` from the `- ...cellForRowAtIndexPath:...` method.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, moving [tableView reloadData]; to request completion handler solved the empty tableview issue. The data I am trying to load is not showing however. It is definitely being loaded successfully, (able to NSLog), but I think I am doing something wrong while adding it to a new NSdictionary because tableview returns nulls.
I don't disagree, I should read and learn, that is exactly what I am trying to do as well, it is my 2nd day doing/seeing objective-C, and I am glad that people are being helpful here.

Comment: Okay, I got it...found the right way to output the array into the rows.